# Calling a non static method from a static Handler in Android

Tags: android

I've been googling this day and I can't find a simple solution that answers my question.  I have the Lint warning "This Handler class should be static or leaks might occur" So I follow the logic as proposed by Romain Guy and many others and constructed my Handler as follows..

```
public static class MyHandler extends Handler {
    private final WeakReference<CustomTrophyCreateActivity> mActivity;

    MyHandler(CustomTrophyCreateActivity activity) {
        mActivity = new WeakReference<CustomTrophyCreateActivity>(activity);
    }

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {

    if (mActivity != null) {
    Activity activity = mActivity.get();
        if (activity != null) {
            // Call non static method in enclosing activity.. CANT DO THIS
            startUploadPhoto();
        }
    }           
}
```

So the basic question is.. how to I call this non-static method from a Handler that has been made static to avoid memory leaks??

I really would like to avoid making startUploadPhoto() static, because 1) It doesn't need to be and 2) It would require a lot of work changing variables.  I fully understand why this lint warning is popping up.. I just can't seem to find a simple solution to rid myself of it.  Thank you.

Comment: You have your Activity right there, don't you?

Comment: Yes the activity is the enclosing class.  I don't see where you are going.

Comment: Can't you just do `activity.startUploadPhoto();`? (if properly typed)

Comment: Ah,  see my error.. I tried that but the lint marker remained.. what I didn't realize is that the lint marker changed.. it was requiring a cast from activity to CustomTrophyCreateActivity.. I guess it saves time (like hours) to hover over the lint marker after making changes :(  I assumed it was the same error.. that's almost funny in a pathetic way.

Comment: Well.. things are odd.. Please see my edited question.  Thanks for your time.

Comment: Sounds like lingering markers?

Comment: Yes. that is it.. what a total pain.  Eclipse is honestly trying to ruin my night.. Next on the list I'm sure will be a git meltdown.  Thanks for your kind understanding sagely help!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use your reference to invoke the method, not the the implicit enclosing class.   Try `activity.startUploadPhoto();`

Comment: Thanks, see my comment above.  I was going crazy.  Just needed to cast.